# Domino designer run selected frameset when program start

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I know that in settings is option where can set main frameset what will be show when program run (previrew in Notes), but I can't find this option anywhere, please help me.

For example I have Frameset "Menu" and I want run this frameset when I press "Preview in Notes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting "Open designated Frameset" is on the Launch tab of the database properties:

[image]